# Time varying input ODE solving

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations, equation-solving, ode45

I'm trying to solve a set of ODE equations using `ode45`. A number of my parameters are already a function of time but I keep getting errors.

```
function odo
dx(1,1) = (vl+vr)/2*cos(x(3));
dx(2,1) = (vl+vr)/2*sin(x(3));
dx(3,1) = obz
```

where `obz`, `vr` and `vl` are each vectors e.g:

```
obz = sin(t),    t = 0:dt:tf;
```

I use the following syntax:

```
[t, x1] = ode45(@(t,x) odo(t,x,b,obz,vr,vl), 0:dt:tf, [0;0;0]);
```

with `R15` but keep getting the error:

> Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You have no in- or outputs declared to `odo`, why is that?

Comment: What do you mean with "obz, vr and vl are each vectors"? Do you mean like in the code after that that they are functions of t that are given as a function table? Or that they are functions that are given as a formula?

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors here. First You can't just type `function odo` and let the MATLAB guess what it should do here. The second, you call `t` and `x` twice in your solver expressions. Be consistent, call function in ode solver this way:

```
t_span=1:1:12;
b=0.2;
[t, x] = ode45(@odo, t_span, [0;0;0], b);
```

You don't need to pass `t` and `x` manually, solver do it itself. Only the additional parameter `b` (however it is not in use, in your example). Also in declaration of function do as follow:

```
function dx = odo(t,x,b)

vr=sin(t); %Non-OD equations here
vl=cos(t);
obz=0.05*sin(t);

n=numel(x); %this generate a holder for results
dx=zeros(n,1);

dx(1) = (vl+vr)/2*cos(x(3)); %All ODEs formatted like this
dx(2) = (vl+vr)/2*sin(x(3));
dx(3) = obz;
```

As you can see, `vr`, `vl`, and `obz` are time-depended values, so need to be re-calculated in every step of solver. You have to place it in your solver function.

Comment: Hi karls.Thanks. I did as you said but now it can't recognize x and t because I guess the way you described it, both t and x will be considered as parameters of the equation and not what needs to be solved.`Undefined function or variable 'x'.` the following info can be used :` t=1:1:12;` `vr=sin(t)`,`vl=cos(t)`;`obz=0.05*sin(t)` b=0.2

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. I edited my answer, now it should run without errors. Good luck!